# iOS - Removing UITabBarViewController Shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, quartz-core

I have a `UITabBarController` hooked up with the `PPRevealSideViewController` library for side-menu navigation (the attached image is in transition from the tab bar view to the right-side view controller, which contains an `MKMapView`).

I want to remove the drop shadow seen on the `UITabBarController`'s view. I've tried placing the following in `ViewDidLoad` of the `SLTabBarController.m` file, which implements my `UITabBarController`:

```
self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
self.view.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

I've also tried using `self.view.tabBarController.layer` and `self.view.layer.hidden = YES;` to no avail.

Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

[image: Transitioning from tab bar controller to right-side view controller with map.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shadow is created by the PPRevealSideViewController library you're using, not by UITabBarController.
From taking a quick peak at the [PPRevealSideViewController docs](https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController), it looks like you can disable shadows with the `PPRevealSideOptionsShowShadows` option.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that, didn’t realize it’s something that has to be changed in the library’s header file.